# Specifying path of included module

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to load a module from within addon code (not content script) that is compatible with CommonJS but which **itself requires a module whose path needs to be specified**.

After reading through the documentation for `toolkit/loader`, I thought I could accomplish what I'm after by simply creating a custom `Loader` and specifying a `modules` export in its options.  Like so:

```
let { Loader, Module, load } = require("toolkit/loader");
let self = require("sdk/self");

// `bar` is required by `foo`
let loader = Loader({
  modules: {
    "bar": require("./bar")
  }
});

let module = Module("foo", self.data.url("../lib/foo.js"));
load(loader, module);
```

And in `foo`, I simply require `bar`:

```
require("bar");
```

For whatever reason, this approach doesn't work.  Maybe it requires the use of `Cu.import` or some such.  The documentation is anything but clear.

I then took a different approach, one relying on specifying the `paths` attribute:

```
let self = require("sdk/self");
let loader = Loader({
  paths: {
    "bar": self.data.url("../lib/bar.js"),
  }
});

let module = Module("foo", self.data.url("../lib/foo.js"));
load(loader, module);
```

But now nothing pertaining to the SDK loads inside `foo`. For instance, the following fails:

```
require("sdk/timers")
```

This seems to imply that additional initialisation of the `Loader` instance is required but I've no clue where to start.

Questions:

1. how can I specify the path to a module that is included somewhere without that causing havoc?
2. how can I retrieve the URL of an asset in the extension's `lib` directory?  I'm currently using `require("sdk/self").data.url("../lib/asset")`, as you can see above,  but surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
There is a simple way to load commonJS based modules.
for ex: if the below is folder structure of your add-on,
data\foo.js,
data\bar.js

then foo.js can simply include bar.js using the syntax.
var bar = require('bar');
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I know how to use require.  The problem is that the module I'm loading, although compatible with CommonJS form, requires a dependency whose path MUST be specified.